# Probability - Tree Diagram

Tags: probability, statistics

Research in a town shows that if it rains on any one day then the probability that it will rain the following day is $25\%$. If it does $not$ rain one day then the probability that it will rain the following day is $12\%$. Starting on a Monday and given that it rains on that Monday:

i) Draw a probability tree diagram to illustrate the information, and show the probability on ALL of the branches.

ii) Determine the probability that it will rain on the Wednesday of that week.

I'm having some trouble understanding the question. Please assist. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the tree, the numbers are the probabilities of each event:

[image]

Comment: So let me put it into words: It rains on Monday, therefore there is a 25% probability that it will rain on tuesday, but 75% that it till be dry, therefore we can assume that it didn't rain on tuesday since the probability is higher, and from the question it states that if it doesn't rain on the day, the probability that it will rain the following day is 12%, leaving 88% for Wednesday. Correct?

Comment: You cannot assume that it didn't rain on Tuesday, you have to consider both possibilities: it rains with probability $0.25$ and it does not with probability $0.75$ (since it rained on Monday).

Comment: Okay ... So for ii) the probability that it will rain on the Wednesday of that week is = 0.0625 + 0.090 = 0.1525 ... Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.